# Writing files and executing. py files on android python 3

Tags: android, python-3.x, tablet, sony, sony-xperia

I am using python 3 on my Sony xperia talet z android device, and have transfered my python project over to it.

My python programs write and create/remove files, stored in a DATA folder. On my PCs, my programs work fine, and can successfuly do so without any problems, however when I run my programs on android, they say that the files are read only. Is there a way to make files and folders writable on android?

Also, my programs are all linked together, so that you can run one from within the other, e.g. I have a main menu, and can run a program by typing in which one to run, and then can return back to the main menu. But on my android tablet, it comes uo with an error that it cannot find the program.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you edit into your question the exact error message you are getting, and how you are calling one file from another, and how you are launching the first file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becaouse you need to give file permissions to android.
what do you use to start your python app? Python3 for Android?
With python3 I've never tried it, but it takes python2.7 with the recipes and then when the project is complex, you have to compile your project with python python to make it a 4 Android APK with prmission appropriate in your case reads / write filesystem.

To deploy of your python app on android you can see [Buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer)

and there is also a tool that integrates graphics, you can see [Kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kiv)

Hope this help you